# Writing prototypes instead of #include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, language-lawyer, stdio

For example, here is a "hello, world" program without `stdio.h` included:

```
int puts(const char *str);

int main(void)
{
    puts("hello, world");
}
```

I even think this can be a good programming style when my program gets longer and longer, for all functions called are listed at the beginning explicitly.

So my question is: Besides providing prototypes for standard library functions, what else does `#include <stdio.h>` do?

Comment: Certain functions may be defined as macros

Comment: You can look up all the things `stdio.h` provides by browsing the C99 standard, section **7.21 Input/output `<stdio.h>`**

Comment: It's a very bad idea to declare external functions yourself rather than including the appropriate header file.  It's not clear what problem you think you're solving, but I can assure you, you're not.

Comment: Also all functions beside few basic ones demand some complex data structures. So you have to be especially careful declaring them exactly the same way they defined in the library

Comment: Not including the standard includes for the standard functions you use is very bad practice.

Comment: The advantage of including headers is that you use the actual prototypes that the library or objects were compiled against. Why introduce the risk of errors?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? unless you have a better solution

Comment: Not only does this increase the amount of code you need to write, it's not portable.  It's not even portable between versions of a single compiler!!  The only advantage I see here is potentially improved compilation speed, and that can be solved with precompiled headers.  It's definitely **not** good programming style.

Comment: I have done what you expressed without issue before, but this only works for tiny programs (as in a "Hello world" program, but not much larger). This also assumes you don't need to explicitly need to use `stderr` and file handling functions. Even if I did this, `<stdio.h>` would be one header that I'd still include for that reason. On the other hand, something like `char *strchr(const char *, int);` I'd have no problem with. One disadvantage is that some implementations may provide inline-assembly versions of functions via macros that don't need to set up a procedure stack and such.

Comment: On that note, I'd say why not include the header and `#undef FUNCNAME` if you want to declare which standard functions you use?

Comment: I think it is bad programming style as you may inadvertently put a prototype that does not match the function definition

Comment: It is bad C programming style because the C standard says the behaviour is undefined, no other reasons needed.

Comment: There is a very easy way to find out whats in stdio.h, read it.

Comment: My reading of standard was too strict initially: Keith Thompson pointed out that it is permissible to declare a prototype for a stdlib function provided that the prototype does not reference any types declared in the header file.

Comment: I'd like to add that, some function declations in library headers include additional pragmas. These might increase diagnostic messages or provide optimization opportunities. If you won't include header, you'll lose them. One example: `printf` function often has pragma which forces to compiler to do argument type checking, and throw warning if incorrect type specifier is used.

Comment: Also, this question should not have been closed as too broad. Wording on the question is a bit loose (*"what else does #include <stdio.h> do?"*), but the point of the question is clear and compact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (non-normative) Appendix J.2 of the C11 standard draft lists the following among examples of undefined behaviour:

> —  A  function,  object,  type,  or  macro  that  is  specified  as  being  declared  or  defined  by some standard header is used before any header that declares or defines it is included (7.1.2)

However, as pointed out by Keith Thompson, the 7.1.4p2 says:

> 2 Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header,  it  is  also  permissible  to  declare  the  function  and  use  it  without  including  its associated header.

Thus using `puts` without including `<stdio.h>` can indeed be done in standard-conforming manner. However, you cannot declare `fputs`, since it requires a pointer-to-`FILE` as an argument, which you cannot do in a strictly conforming manner.

In addition, `puts` might also be a macro in presence of `<stdio.h>` and expand to something faster in the presence of the header.

All in all, the number of functions that can be declared properly without including headers is not that large. As for the functions that use some types from the headers - if you're asking with **language-lawyer** tag about C, the answer comes from the standard and the standard is rather outspoken about this: don't do it, or your program will not be strictly conforming, period.

Comment: But 7.1.4p2 is normative: "Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type deﬁned in a
header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its
associated header."

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, somehow missed it, upvoted yours.

Answer (score 5):

`<stdio.h>` defines the type `FILE`, among other things. You can't portably call any function that takes a `FILE*` parameter or returns a `FILE*` result without `#include <stdio.h>`.

And there's really no good reason to declare any of the functions yourself rather than including the header.

Answer (score 1):

When using proper program design, all prototypes of public functions are placed in header files and all function definitions are placed in c files. This is how you write C programs, period.

It is the industry de facto standard way of C programming and no professionals use any other design.

Your personal preference is not relevant here, nor are any loop-holes in the C standard that would allow you to make a different design. You should write your C programs in the same way as the rest of the world does.